# dithering using 1x2 blocks

Tags: pixel, pixelation, pixel-art

Is there any software, which can do "block error diffusion" dithering as described [here](http://caca.zoy.org/study/part3.html) and [here](http://caca.zoy.org/study/part5.html)? Often I end up with completely separated pixels of the same colour, when doing Floyd Steinberg dithering. I would like pixel blocks of 1x2 or 2x2 pixels of the same colour to be united. Is it possible with any existing software? I am happy to write the code myself. I just need to know what the approach is.

I only want the final image to contain pixel blocks of size 1x2 like these:
[image: 1x2 pixels black and white]
[image: 1x2 pixels 4 shades of gray]

Comment: Could you give a visual example of what you're looking for? I'm not sure what you mean by "separated pixels of the same colour"

Comment: You can do this with Photoshop or most software. That support layering modes and scaling.

Comment: Thanks @alex-blackwood. I have updated my question and added image examples.

Comment: The guide you linked in your question includes all of the relevant code to create this sort of dither [the source code included at the end.](http://caca.zoy.org/study/study.py) Specifically, the `subblock` function defined in the Chapter 5 section

Comment: @AlexBlackwood I'm not sure how I could have missed that. Thanks a million! Please leave it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: This question is an excellent example of the ... gray area ... between stackoverflow and graphic design sx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The study of the library to which you linked](http://caca.zoy.org/study/index.html) includes [all of the python code necessary](http://caca.zoy.org/study/source.html) to generate all of the images examples contained in the document.

The attaced code is a copy of the relevant functions needed to create an error corrected dither of arbitrary tiles. It takes an image as an input(foo.png) and creates two PNG files as output (foo_GreyDither.png, foo_BWDither.png)

For example, `python ditherCode.py foo.png`

[image: test image of a girl's face]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math, gd, random, sys, os

class Image(gd.image):
    gd.gdMaxColors = 256 * 256 * 256
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if args[0].__class__ == str:
            print "[LOAD] %s" % (args[0],)
        gd.image.__init__(self, *args)
    def save(self, name):
        print "[PNG] %s" % (name,)
        self.writePng(name)
    def getGray(self, x, y):
        p = self.getPixel((x, y))
        c = self.colorComponents(p)[0] / 255.0
        return c
    def getRgb(self, x, y):
        p = self.getPixel((x, y))
        rgb = self.colorComponents(p)
        return [rgb[0] / 255.0, rgb[1] / 255.0, rgb[2] / 255.0]
    def setGray(self, x, y, t):
        p = (int)(t * 255.999)
        c = self.colorResolve((p, p, p))
        self.setPixel((x, y), c)
    def setRgb(self, x, y, r, g, b):
        r = (int)(r * 255.999)
        g = (int)(g * 255.999)
        b = (int)(b * 255.999)
        c = self.colorResolve((r, g, b))
        self.setPixel((x, y), c)
    def getRegion(self, x, y, w, h):
        dest = Image((w, h), True)
        self.copyTo(dest, (-x, -y))
        return dest
    def getZoom(self, z):
        (w, h) = self.size()
        dest = Image((w * z, h * z), True)
        for y in range(h):
            for x in range(w):
                rgb = self.getRgb(x, y)
                for j in range(z):
                    for i in range(z):
                        dest.setRgb(x * z + i, y * z + j, *rgb)
        return dest

# Manipulate gamma values
class Gamma:
    def CtoI(x):
        if x < 0:
            return - math.pow(-x, 2.2)
        return math.pow(x, 2.2)
    def ItoC(x):
        if x < 0:
            return - math.pow(-x, 1 / 2.2)
        return math.pow(x, 1 / 2.2)
    CtoI = staticmethod(CtoI)
    ItoC = staticmethod(ItoC)
    def CtoI3(x):
        return [Gamma.CtoI(x[0]), Gamma.CtoI(x[1]), Gamma.CtoI(x[2])]
    def ItoC3(x):
        return [Gamma.ItoC(x[0]), Gamma.ItoC(x[1]), Gamma.ItoC(x[2])]
    CtoI3 = staticmethod(CtoI3)
    ItoC3 = staticmethod(ItoC3)
    def Cto2(x):
        if x < Gamma.CtoI(0.50):
            return 0.
        return 1.
    def Cto3(x):
        if x < Gamma.CtoI(0.25):
            return 0.
        elif x < Gamma.CtoI(0.75):
            return Gamma.CtoI(0.5)
        return 1.
    def Cto4(x):
        if x < Gamma.CtoI(0.17):
            return 0.
        elif x < Gamma.CtoI(0.50):
            return Gamma.CtoI(0.3333)
        elif x < Gamma.CtoI(0.83):
            return Gamma.CtoI(0.6666)
        return 1.
    Cto2 = staticmethod(Cto2)
    Cto3 = staticmethod(Cto3)
    Cto4 = staticmethod(Cto4)

# Create matrices
def Matrix(w, h, val = 0):
    return [[val] * w for n in range(h)]

# Iterate in 2D space
def rangexy(w, h):
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            yield (x, y)

inputImage = Image(sys.argv[1])
# grad256bw = Image((32, 256))
# for x, y in rangexy(32, 256):
#     grad256bw.setGray(x, 255 - y, y / 255.)
# grad256bw.save("gradient256bw.png")

def subblock(src, tiles, propagate, diff, gamma):
    (w, h) = src.size()
    # Gamma correction
    if gamma:
        ctoi = Gamma.CtoI
        itoc = Gamma.ItoC
    else:
        ctoi = itoc = lambda x : x
    # Propagating the error to a temporary buffer is becoming more and
    # more complicated. We decide to use an intermediate matrix instead.
    tmp = Matrix(w, h, 0.)
    for x, y in rangexy(w, h):
        tmp[y][x] = ctoi(src.getGray(x, y))
    dest = Image((w, h))
    # Analyse tile list
    ntiles = len(tiles)
    ty = len(tiles[0])
    tx = len(tiles[0][0])
    cur = Matrix(tx, ty, 0.)
    w, h = w / tx, h / ty
    # Analyse error propagate list
    for x, y in rangexy(w, h):
        # Get block value
        for i, j in rangexy(tx, ty):
            cur[j][i] = itoc(tmp[y * ty + j][x * tx + i])
        # Select closest block
        dist = tx * ty
        for n in range(ntiles):
            d = 0.
            e = 0.
            for i, j in rangexy(tx, ty):
                d += cur[j][i] - tiles[n][j][i]
                e += diff[j][i] * abs(cur[j][i] - tiles[n][j][i])
            if abs(d) / (tx * ty) + e < dist:
                dist = abs(d) / (tx * ty) + e
                best = n
        # Set pixel
        for i, j in rangexy(tx, ty):
            dest.setGray(x * tx + i, y * ty + j, tiles[best][j][i])
        # Propagate error
        for i, j in rangexy(tx, ty):
            e = ctoi(cur[j][i]) - ctoi(tiles[best][j][i])
            m = propagate[j][i]
            for px, py in rangexy(len(m[0]), len(m)):
                if m[py][px] == 0:
                    continue
                if m[py][px] == -1:
                    cx, cy = px, py
                    continue
                tmpx = x * tx + i + px - cx
                tmpy = y * ty + j + py - cy
                if tmpx > w * tx - 1 or tmpy > h * ty - 1:
                    continue
                tmp[tmpy][tmpx] += m[py][px] * e
    return dest

ERROR_SUBFS22 = \
    [[[[0, -1, 0, 8./64],
       [0, 0, 0, 10./64],
       [7./64, 22./64, 15./64, 2./64]],
      [[0, 0, -1, 20./64],
       [0, 0, 0, 14./64],
       [2./64, 11./64, 15./64, 2./64]]],
     [[[0, 0, 0, 0./64],
       [0, -1, 0, 6./64],
       [12./64, 32./64, 13./64, 1./64]],
      [[0, 0, 0, 0./64],
       [0, 0, -1, 20./64],
       [0./64, 12./64, 28./64, 4./64]]]]

DIFF_WEIGHTED22 = \
    [[51./128, 33./128],
     [25./128, 19./128]]

GREYLINES22 = []
for n in range(4*4*4*4):
    vals = [0., 0.333, 0.666, 1.]
    a, b, c, d = n & 3, (n >> 2) & 3, (n >> 4) & 3, (n >> 6) & 3
    if (a != b or c != d) and (a != c or b != d):
        continue
    GREYLINES22.append([[vals[a], vals[b]], [vals[c], vals[d]]])

LINES22 = \
    [[[0., 0.], [0., 0.]],
     [[0., 1.], [0., 1.]],
     [[1., 0.], [1., 0.]],
     [[1., 1.], [0., 0.]],
     [[0., 0.], [1., 1.]],
     [[1., 1.], [1., 1.]]]

foo = sys.argv[1]
foo = foo[:-4]

subblock(inputImage, GREYLINES22,
         ERROR_SUBFS22, DIFF_WEIGHTED22, False).save(foo+"_GreyDither.png")
subblock(inputImage, LINES22,
         ERROR_SUBFS22, DIFF_WEIGHTED22, False).save(foo+"_BWDither.png")
```